# Eclipse RCP Obfuscation

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, obfuscation, tycho

I have built a Eclipse RCP Application and packaged with Maven/Tycho and everything works fine. Now, I want to protect my code and want to obfuscate it.
Here are the list of questions :-

1. Which free tool to use for Obfuscating RCP application?? I tried
   Proguard, but stuck with the configuration file and not able to run
   Obfuscation. Unfortunately, I dont have sample Eclipse RCP Proguard
   Config file.
2. When should the obfuscation be done?? After the
   complete Maven Install of application or when the application is
   packaging.

I have tried all possible Google solutions but in vein. Appreciate if any one could be of help.

Regards,
SDS.

Answer (score 0):

### Which free tool to use for Obfuscating RCP application

There are some existing plugins you can search in marketplace which help in Obfuscating for example:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/stringer-java-obfuscator

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-antidecompiler

### When should the obfuscation be done??

I have used Obfuscating my RCP application when I do not want to show my package name, method name while extracting code, the objective behind was that we have write down a very specific tool which had some genius and patent code and we do not want to make it free. Simply, in case when you do not want to show your logic.

### Approach:

We did in a way that all package names and method names will appear like `"OOOOOMMEEOOOOOOOOO"` or `"EEEEEXXXXXOOOOXX"` while extracting or decompiling. you can also write your own logic to replicate specifically what you need and what you target.

It would be good which API or part of code or jar you want to Obfuscating, in my case, RCP application was combination of four applications and we did Obfuscating for our patent code jar only.

You can also refer this:

https://rcpquickstart.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/obfuscating-an-rcp-application/

Comment: thank you for the links, I wanted more info on Proguard Config files for Obfuscation. Stringer is licensed software and I looking for any free obfuscation software.